# How to convert hex to dec manually in python?

Tags: python

This is my first time using this QnA site... I had this task in my class which asks me to convert numbers from any basis into decimal using method... I'm very confused about converting alphabets contained in a hex number. Here is the program which I type:

```
def base_n_to_dec(num_string, base):
    dec = 0
    index = len(num_string) - 1
    for digit in num_string:
        dec += int(digit) * (base ** index)
        index -= 1
    return dec
```

Could anyone please help me to modify this program so it could recognize the alphabets contained in hex numbers, so it could convert the characters to decimal basis? Please don't use built-in functions, because it's not allowed. (I already submitted the task, so I don't mean asking someone to finish my assignment) sorry for the bad english...

Comment: In other words, this works when you don't have any of 'A-F', and you don't know how to make that part work?

Comment: Have a look at how to create a [mcve]. Start with simple test cases. If even a basic minimal case doesn't work, just think about that, try to get it working, post the input and expected output.

Comment: You just have to map A to 10, B to 11, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEF'

def base_n_to_dec(num_string, base):
    '''
        :param num_string: string containing number in base10
        :param base: integer between 2 and 16
        :returns: num_string based base as a string
    '''
    b10_num = 0
    for digit in num_string:
         b10_num *= 10
         b10_num += alphabet.index(digit)
    if b10_num == 0:
        return '0'
    result = ''
    while b10_num > 0:
        result = alphabet[b10_num % base] + result
        b10_num /= base
    return result
```